# discord.js ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el bot diga en el chat aleatoriamente 0 o 1?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer algo que tiene un 50% de posibilidades de que suceda algo y un 50% de posibilidades de que suceda algo más, y es por eso que los 0 y los 1.

Mi código:

```
    var num = [0,1];
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(num.length));

    if (random < 1) { //Win
        message.channel.send("Win");
    }
    else { //To Lose
        message.channel.send("Lose");
    }
```

Comment: y qué evento lo dispararía?? Tenés el resto del código para enviar al canal y sólo te falta el aleatorio? ¿Podrías por favor [edit] tu pregunta para mostrar el código con lo que tenés hecho?

Comment: @Pollo Ya la he editado

Comment: Gracias por agregar. pero esto está siendo disparado cuando recibe algún mensaje del usuario. ¿En qué evento está esta parte del código? Y en concreto, ¿estás seguro que `message` es el parámetro que recibe la función asociada al evento y que es exclusivamente un mensaje de un canal? ¿Qué problema / error te está trayendo?

Comment: O sea, ¿esto está dentro de algo como: `client.on('message', message => {` ... `});`   ?

Comment: No me está dando ningún error, simplemente el bot no responde, y si está dentro de un client.on('message', message => { ... });

Comment: ¿Podrás agregar el código completo entonces? Es imposible responderte a un error que no está en la parte del código que estás mostrando. ¿Intentaste depurarlo? ¿si antes que esta parte, intentás enviar un mensaje, lo envía? ¿hay algo en el log de Node?